# Rearranging $\{p_j\}$ and $\{q_j\}$ into one sequence $\{r_j\}$ with $s_n \geqslant 0$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I'm trying to prove Lemma $2$ in [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2042145) paper. The statement is as follows:

> Let $\{p_j\}$ be a sequence (possibly finite) of non-negative numbers, and $\{-q_j\}$ be an infinite sequence of negative numbers such that $\sum p_j = \sum q_j \leqslant \infty$, $q_j \to 0$ as $j\to\infty$, and $p_j \to 0$ in case $\{p_j\}$ is an infinite sequence. Then these two sequences can be arranged into one sequence $\{r_j\}$ such that
>
> 1. $s_n = r_1 + \ldots + r_n \geqslant 0$ for all $n$, and
> 2. $s_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

If any $p_i$ equals $0$, we can simply discard it since it doesn't alter any of the sums. Now, put $r_1 := p_1 > 0$. If $q_1 < p_1$, put $r_2 := -q_1$. Otherwise, keep looking until you find a $q_k$ such that $q_k < p_1$ and put $r_2 := -q_k$. We can find such a $q_k$ since $\lim_{j\to\infty} q_j = 0$. I could keep picking terms from either sequence and (hopefully) ensure that $s_n \geqslant 0$ while $s_n \to 0$, but it is not clear why this process would work and terminate.

My idea for a proof is constructive/algorithmic, but I couldn't see it to completion. Perhaps there is a better, non-constructive approach? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The algorithm is good. Of course if both input sequences are infinite it won't ever terminate, but it's normal to specify infinite sequences by induction. The task is to show that this algorithm does use every element $p_j$ and every element $q_j$ exactly once and does satisfy the two properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before starting the answer, I would like to say that, $p_k$ is finite is equivalent to say that for some integer $n$, $p_k = 0$ whenever $k\ge n$.

I would start by using induction to construct a strictly increasing sequence of intergers $\left(m_\ell\right)_{\ell\in \mathbb N}$ such that $m_0 = 0$

> $$\sum_{k=1}^{m_\ell} p_k -\sum_{j=1}^\ell q_j > 0;\; \forall \ell\in \mathbb N_{\ge 1}$$

First, since $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k - q_1 = \sum_{j=2}^\infty q_j > 0$$ then one cann obtain an integer $m_1$ such that, $$\sum_{k=1}^{m_1} p_k - q_1 > 0.$$

Now assume that you have constructed $m_1, m_2, \ldots, m_\ell$. To construct $m_{\ell + 1}$ use the fact that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k - \sum_{j=1}^\ell q_j = \sum_{j=\ell+1}^\infty q_j > 0.$$

This ended the induction.

Now let $$r_k =\begin{cases}p_{k-\ell} & \text{if $m_\ell + \ell < k \le m_{\ell + 1} + \ell$}\\
-q_{\ell + 1} & \text{if $k = m_{\ell} + \ell$}
\end{cases}$$

Let $n\in \mathbb N_{\ge 1}$ and $\ell$ such that $m_\ell + \ell < n \le m_{\ell+1} +\ell$

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n r_k &\ge \sum_{k=1}^{m_\ell} p_k - \sum_{j=1}^\ell q_j \ge 0
\end{align}

this proves $s_n \ge 0$. For the limit:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty r_k &= \lim\limits_{\ell \to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m_\ell} p_k - \sum_{j=1}^\ell q_j\right) = 0.
\end{align}

---

Basically the idea is just at each time add a bunch of terms $p_j$ that will ensure when adding the next term $-q_j$ you will have a non-negative value.

Comment: Yes I corrected the typos that I had in the answer.

Comment: $p_k$ means that at certain moment $p$ will be $0$.

Comment: $p$ is the sequence $p_k$.

Comment: I will edit my answer to include some details.

Comment: Don't you mean $$r_k =\begin{cases}p_{k-\ell} & \text{if $m_\ell + \ell < k \le m_{\ell + 1} + \ell$}\\
-q_{\ell + 1} & \text{if $k = m_{\ell+1} + \ell+1$}
\end{cases}
$$
instead? See what happens when $\ell = 0$, we want to add $-q_1$ first, right? There is no $q_0$.

Comment: Yes that correct in some way! I edited my answer to include that.

Comment: Last suggestion: you may want to replace $$\sum_{k=1}^{m_\ell} p_k -\sum_{j=1}^\ell q_j > 0;\; \forall \ell\in \mathbb N_{\ge 1}$$ with $$\sum_{k=1}^{m_\ell} p_k -\sum_{j=1}^\ell q_j \geqslant 0;\; \forall \ell\in \mathbb N_{\ge 1}$$

Comment: Ok if you want so. But both of them are true!